# Was the input function in python updated?

Tags: python

I'm doing this course on python by cisco and learning about the input function it says if i run a code like this

```
anything = input("Enter a number: ")
something = anything ** 2.0
print(anything, "to the power of 2 is", something)
```

the console should show this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File ".main.py", line 4, in <module>
something = anything ** 2.0
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'float'
```

But when i run it with python shell for example i get the actual result

```
Enter a number: 5
(5.0, 'to the power of 2 is', 25.0)
```

Does it validates the value automatically now? or is this a bug or something?

Comment: Sounds like you’re following a course for Python 2. Don’t. Look for another course. Python 2 is dead and gone.

Comment: Or the other way around, you’re running code for Python 3 on Python 2…

Comment: At the start of the course it specified that it is a Python 3 course and i'm using the last version of the python IDLE.

Comment: If you’re getting `(5.0, 'to the power of 2 is', 25.0)` as output from that code, you are running Python 2.

Comment: I just checked and i was indeed operating with Python 2 i just updated it and it's now working as intended thanks for the help.